# Why Angular Material compareWith function only compares first value?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material2

**Object from API:**

```
roles = {
    admin: false,
    user: true,
}
```

**Template:**

```
<mat-select formControlName="roles" required multiple [compareWith]="compareRoles">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let role of roleList" [value]="role">{{role}}</mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

Component:

```
this.roles = ['admin', 'user']

createForm(): FormGroup
{
    return this._formBuilder.group({
        roles : [[this.roles]],
    })
}
```

compareWith function:

```
public compareRoles(c1: any, c2: any): boolean {
    return true
}
```

---

**Expected behavior with compareWith function always returning true:** Both 'admin' and 'user' should be checked.

**Actual behavior:** Only 'admin' is checked. Function does not execute check for 'user'.

Why is only the first value in my roles array being compared? Also, why isn't both 'admin' and 'user' checked when the compareWith function always returns true?

Comment: I suppose that MatSelect assume different object are passed, with key matching only one, so compareWith stop on the first match.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you wish to dynamically add new entries to your drop-down which will require the compareWith directive. Please see this link for a simple example - https://netbasal.com/understanding-the-comparefn-input-in-angular-v4-4a401ef4fc4c

With that said, I think your compare method should be as follows -

```
roles = {
 {id:admin, value:false},
 {id:user, value:true}
}

public compareRoles(c1: any, c2: any): boolean {
  return c1.value == c2.value;
}
```